# Using sequelize-cli with multiple databases

Tags: node.js

**New to using sequelize.**
I wish to use a mysql and a mongodb for my app. My tables are already present in the mysql db and now I wish to migrate those tables to mongodb using sequelize.

```
    {
  "mysql":{
    "development": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "guidhwbq_guideVilla",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql",
      "logging":true
    },
    "test": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "guidhwbq_guideVilla",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    },
    "production": {
      "username": "root",
      "password": "",
      "database": "guidhwbq_guideVilla",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "dialect": "mysql"
    }
  },
  "mongo" : {
    "url" : "mongodb://localhost:27017/guidhwbq_guideVilla"
  }
}
```

Above is my config file. How should I proceed with the models and migrations file?
I know how to code both files for single database but I am having trouble using multiple DBs.